# Getting touch coordinates Cordova + Android with Galaxy S4

Tags: android, html, cordova, coordinates

Hello I've a problem to get coordinates in a Phonegap webapp and Android (testing in Galaxy S4).

with this code

```
$('#canvas_div').bind("touchstart", function (event) {
   canvas_x = event.pageX;
   canvas_y = event.pageY - OffsetRadar;
});
```

I've tried to use `event.touches[0].pageX` or `event.screenX` but are undefined.

Could you help me? (I've tried other solutions found in stackoverflow!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#canvas_div').bind("touchstart", function (e) {
   var touch = e.touches[0];
   canvas_x = touch.pageX;
   canvas_y = touch.pageY - OffsetRadar;
});
```

Edit:

```
$('#canvas_div').bind("touchstart", function (e) {
   var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
   canvas_x = touch.pageX;
   canvas_y = touch.pageY - OffsetRadar;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I try this code the console give me this error

12-12 18:06:14.206: E/Web Console(27212): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined:10